# How to add a string from an array to scandir without adding a ghost space

Tags: php, mysqli, scandir

When I grab the directory string from the array `$rawgendir=$row['gendir'];` 
scandir returns the error

```
"Warning: scandir( ALABAMA/CITIES ABBEVILLE - ALABAMA REVENUE ENFORCEMENT/ , ALABAMA/CITIES ABBEVILLE - ALABAMA REVENUE ENFORCEMENT/ ): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)"
```

Defining the path explicitly in the var $dir works, just doen't apply to what I am trying to create. In this case a search engine for images

I think the problem is, I am getting a ghost space in `scandir( ALABAMA/...)` And I don't see how. I have been working at this for a long time because I am definitely not a programmer yet.

```
 //$searchstring PULLED FROM _POST
 $db_conx = (MYSQLi CONNECTION)
 $sql="SELECT *  FROM `main` WHERE CONVERT(`title` USING utf8) LIKE '%" . $SearchString . "%'";

$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

//-create while loop and loop through result set
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$patchtitle=$row['title'];
$id=$row['id'];
$patchpath=$row['dir'];
$rawgendir=$row['gendir'];
echo $rawgendir;
```

This line

```
echo $rawgendir;
```

prints out `ALABAMA/CITIES ABBEVILLE   -   ALABAMA REVENUE ENFORCEMENT/`
without the mystery space

```
// $dir = ("ALABAMA/CITIES ABBEVILLE   -   ALABAMA REVENUE ENFORCEMENT/");

$fileList = scandir($rawgendir);
//echo $dir;
//echo $rawgendir;
//-display the result o
 echo '
    <table width="864" height="220" border="2">
    <tr>
    <td width="214" height="152"><center>
    <img src="'.$patchpath.' " width="220" height="200" />
    </center></td>
    <td width="632"<h3>Patch: '. $patchtitle . '</h3></td>
     </tr>
    </table> </br>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Please confirm that it is the ghost space that is screwing up your code by adding the line $rawgendir = substr($rawgendir, 1); in your second code portion. if it works, then you have confirmed it is the ghost space causing your issue.

Comment: 'not a programmer yet'.. I would say this question proves otherwise

Comment: Are you certain it's a space? The `scandir()` error looks like a much longer string (duplicating the string) as `ALABAMA/CITIES ABBEVILLE - ALABAMA REVENUE ENFORCEMENT/ , ALABAMA/CITIES ABBEVILLE - ALABAMA REVENUE ENFORCEMENT/`  Check the length of `$rawgendir` with `echo strlen($rawgendir);`

Comment: Well, this has only deepened the mystery. The strings differ in length. There is a ghost space but that didn't help in solving this. [This is the main error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xa49o7cnqhvw7rj/1.PNG?dl=0)

This is what happens when I use $rawgendir = substr($rawgendir, 1) [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhw667ohzr62skc/aformentioned%20new%20error.PNG?dl=0)

This is my [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wluuts8rmo27sxd/2.PNG?dl=0)

some thing to note. the debugger and the echo lines are ignoring whitespaces in the strings, and the outputed strings match exactly when copy and pasted